# How do i find the project of the contents of an ITextViewer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to implement a HyperlinkDetector for an Eclipse plug-in and the callback method is giving me an ITextViewer to work with.

How do i get the project, IPath or IFile of the viewer's IDocument?
Apparently the concept of an IDocument is to only allow access to the content regardless of the source. All i can come up with is to check the active editor part in the workbench...

Since it's Java code i'm working on, the actual type is a JavaSourceViewer if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the article [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html), may be you could look for the right path by asking the [`ITextFileBufferManager`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/filebuffers/ITextFileBufferManager.java.htm)

```
ITextFileBufferManager bufferManager = FileBuffers.getTextFileBufferManager(); // get the buffer manager
```

Use then [`getTextFileBuffer()`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/filebuffers/ITextFileBufferManager.java.htm#ixzz0Z6GM6fsM)

```
 ITextFileBuffer getTextFileBuffer(IDocument document);
```

If you get a [`ITextFileBuffer`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/filebuffers/ITextFileBuffer.java.htm), you can call on it [`getLocation()`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/filebuffers/IFileBuffer.java.htm#ixzz0Z6FqeCkJ) and get back its [`IPath`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath.java.htm).